# Programmaticaly simulate drop internet connection in Golang

Tags: go, testing, websocket

I wrote a websocket client in Go using http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket
I need to write a test for this client, and check how it would behave in case of dropping connection. To do that, I wrote a fake *WebSocket* server. So my question is: how can I simulate down and up again from the server side?

Comment: there a go test packages that can simulate websocket servers

Comment: Can I have a link please?

Comment: Have your mock websocket server refuse connections? Or just try to connect to it while it isn't running?

Comment: I need to have it down, then running again. Just like plug out and then plugi n the cable.

Comment: Set [Dialer.NetDial](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Dialer.NetDial) (or NetDialContext) to a function that wraps the net.Conn with code that simulates whatever failure you want to simulate.

Comment: @RdB: you can't simulate "pulling a cable" in your code, because that's at the wrong layer. Do you want packets null routed? Do you want ICMP HostUnreachable? Do you want ICMP NetworkUnreachable? You need to actually change the network to do that, which can be done physically, or by various means in the OS network stack.